# Python OrderedDict to valid json

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python `OrderedDict` as follows.

```
sample_dict = OrderedDict([('foo', 'bar'), ('foo1', 'bar1')])
```

I need to convert it to valid `JSON`. I tried

```
 json.loads(json.dumps(sample_dict))
```

The output is

```
{'foo1': 'bar1', 'foo': 'bar'}
```

The output contains `single quote` I'm expecting the `double quote`

Answer (score 2):

```
json.dumps(sample_dict)
```

Already returns the JSON, that's enough.

You then feed it to json.loads, which turns it into a Python object in memory again. When you print that, Python is free to choose whether to use `'` or `"` (it really doesn't matter) and happens to choose `'`. But that has nothing to do with JSON.